# How to implement Burp suite's custom SSL Certificate?

Tags: go, ssl, certificate, pkcs#12

In Burp Suite, from `Project Options -> SSL` we can import PKCS#12 files with password for specific hostnames.

I tried manually using commands below to export block and key files and then pass them to my http client in golang using `tls.LoadX509KeyPair()`. But upon sending any requests, I receive `remote error: tls: handshake failure`.

These are the commands I used:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out usercert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -nocerts -out userkey.pem -nodes
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If using a self-signed certificate specify `InsecureSkipVerify: true` in your tls configuration. Pulled from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config):

> ````
>    // InsecureSkipVerify controls whether a client verifies the
>    // server's certificate chain and host name.
>    // If InsecureSkipVerify is true, TLS accepts any certificate
>    // presented by the server and any host name in that certificate.
>    // In this mode, TLS is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
>    // This should be used only for testing.```
> ````

Otherwise, add your certificate to the Certificates list in your tls configuration.

Comment: I do use `InsecureSkipVerify: true` and also added the certificate to tls configuration. Weird thing is when I use curl library it works, but it doesn't work with golang.